# Chromebook Linux Hypnos Lullaby V2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, chromebook

Ok so I have linux on my chromebook and I cd title && wine title.exe --disable-frame-limit

but I do this with Hypnos Lullaby but even though it works with every mod I've tried so far it just doesn't work with this one and the error that keeps popping up is:
[openfl.display.shader]

> ERROR:
> error compiling vertex.shader error:
> GLSL 1.50 is not supported.
> Supported Versions are 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.40, 1.00 ES and 3.00 ES

If anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do except to upgrade your laptop or simply not use that mod.

GLSL support is determined by your graphics drivers and the graphics chip in your laptop.

GLSL [is a part of OpenGL 3.2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Versions), if your laptop supports OpenGL 3.2 the you should have GLSL 1.5. If your laptop has an old GPU that does not support OpenGL 3.2 then there is nothing you can do, the GPU will simply not support the features that the program is using.

Drivers and software cannot fix the hardware not having particular required capabilities.

Comment: Hmm other than those options is there any other option like deleting something in the files that can erase that?